# Generating Thumbnail C# from base64string

Tags: c#, base64, drawing, thumbnails

I am trying to generate a thumbnail from the `base64string`. I am storing the image in a table and am trying to generate a thumbnail from the `base64string` being stored.

I am able to generate the thumbnail if I provide a path to the image, but that will not work in my case.

This is the working solution of generating a thumbnail from an image path:

```
protected void GenerateThumbnail(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string path = Server.MapPath("../src/img/myImage.png");
        System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(path);
        using (System.Drawing.Image thumbnail = image.GetThumbnailImage(100, 100, new System.Drawing.Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort(ThumbnailCallback), IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                thumbnail.Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Png);
                Byte[] bytes = new Byte[memoryStream.Length];
                memoryStream.Position = 0;
                memoryStream.Read(bytes, 0, (int)bytes.Length);
                string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                Image2.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," + base64String;
                Image2.Visible = true;
            }
        }
}
```

Can anyone provide any advice on how to use the `base64string` instead of the image path the generate thumbnail?

Comment: If you want to thumbnail the bitmap, do it before you convert it to base64.  Starting with the base64 string means undoing the last few steps

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: Sorry, the post confused me.  You **have** a base64 string and want to convert it back to bitmap and thumbnail it?

Comment: Yes, I am able to convert the FromFile(path) to a thumbnail, but am unable how to figure converting the base64 to a thumbnail

Comment: `byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(b64);` will convert the b64 string to byte[] which you can use in the memstream ctor

Comment: Yes, but how then do I turn that into a thumbnail?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming, `b64` is the base64 string, you can convert it to a byte array and use that to construct the starting image.

```
byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(b64);
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
{
    Bitmap thumb = new Bitmap(100, 100);
    using (Image bmp = Image.FromStream(ms))
    {
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(thumb))
        { 
            g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            g.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
            g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            g.DrawImage(bmp, 0, 0, 100, 100);
        }
    }
    // a picturebox to show/test the result
    picOut.Image = thumb;
}
```

Be sure to dispose of the thumb when you are done with it.

Comment: Forgot to declare `picOut`

Comment: Hmm... I am getting `Parameter is not valid` on the line where we are declaring the `bmp` variable.. Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like it is not actually saving in base64.. That was the problem

Comment: It is your data - if the B64 doesnt represent image data it would fail on that line.  If it was not really Base64, it should fail on the Convert.From line

Answer (score 2):

Mixed few tricks found online. (one from @Plutonix)

```
string ThumbNailBase64 = ResizeBase64Image(YourBase64String,200, 300);
```

base64 Input => resize => base64 Output

You get the desired thumbnail with auto **aspect ratio**.

```
public static string ResizeBase64Image(string Base64String, int desiredWidth, int desiredHeight)
{
    Base64String = Base64String.Replace("data:image/png;base64,", "");

    // Convert Base64 String to byte[]
    byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(Base64String);

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes))
    {                
        // Convert byte[] to Image
        ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
        Image image = Image.FromStream(ms, true);

        var imag = ScaleImage(image, desiredWidth, desiredHeight);

        using (MemoryStream ms1 = new MemoryStream())
        {
            //First Convert Image to byte[]
            imag.Save(ms1, imag.RawFormat);
            byte[] imageBytes1 = ms1.ToArray();

            //Then Convert byte[] to Base64 String
            string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes1);
            return "data:image/png;base64,"+base64String;
        }
    }
}

public static Image ScaleImage(Image image, int maxWidth, int maxHeight)
{
    var ratioX = (double)maxWidth / image.Width;
    var ratioY = (double)maxHeight / image.Height;
    var ratio = Math.Min(ratioX, ratioY);

    var newWidth = (int)(image.Width * ratio);
    var newHeight = (int)(image.Height * ratio);

    var newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);

    using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
        graphics.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);

    return newImage;
}
```

Comment: Getting a null exception when it tries to access scaledImage.RawFormat. Tried using JPEG format and it doesn't load the images correctly.